# How to attach and remove an event handler programmatically

Tags: jquery

Is there a simple and clear way of writing these 2 functions as a single function without duplication. I think I want to programmatically set the on/off method.

```
function attachEventHandler(){
   $(document).on({
      ajaxStart: function() {
         $("body").addClass("loading");
      },
      ajaxStop: function() {
         $("body").removeClass("loading");
      }
   });
}

function removeEventHandler(){
   $(document).off({
      ajaxStart: function() {
         $("body").addClass("loading");
      },
      ajaxStop: function() {
         $("body").removeClass("loading");
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: There is no `.toggleEvent`

Comment: have a look at the jquery documentation for off: http://api.jquery.com/off/. You don't need to add the functions implementation, just the name of the event you want to remove the handlers for.

Comment: 1) Have a decision flag outside. 2) Remove off logic. 3) Inside `on` do stuff if flag is on. Here we are not removing the event handler instead we are keeping the event handlers and switching off the logic whenever we need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest answer that comes to my mind is

```
var handlers = {
      ajaxStart: function() {
         $("body").addClass("loading");
      },
      ajaxStop: function() {
         $("body").removeClass("loading");
      }
   }

function attachEventHandler(toggle){
   // here we are selecting the 'on' or 'off'
   // property of the $(document) jquery element
   // depending on whether the toggle is true or
   // false. Because the 'on' and 'off' props are
   // functions, we can call the property with
   // `handlers` as the argument
   $(document)[toggle ? 'on' : 'off'](handlers);
}
```

and use it like so:

```
attachEventHandler(true) // turn on
attachEventHandler(false) // turn off
```

Comment: Seems to work a treat @lordvlad. Thanks. Can I just write "toggle" where you have written "toggle === true"? – wurz

Comment: yeah, actually the result will be the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use .on() to bind a function to multiple events:

```
$('#element').on('keyup keypress blur change', function(e) {
// e.type is the type of event fired
});
```

Or just pass the function as the parameter to normal event functions:

```
var myFunction = function() {
...
}

$('#element')
.keyup(myFunction)
.keypress(myFunction)
.blur(myFunction)
.change(myFunction)
```

Comment: OPs question was to do `on` `off` without code duplicate.